# Broken links when redirect to subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a project with the following structure

```
-public_html
-- Mysite
--- Mysite files
```

The following url is a sample of a user request

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite/category.php?id=15
```

I changed the .htaccess to make the URLs more friendly, the .htaccess content is

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /mysite/
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] 
 </IfModule>
```

All is well except that when the user enter the new URL like this

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite/category/15
```

the site is loaded but css and js files url are broken, and every url in the page is written as the following.

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite/category/****.php
```

note that every url has unneeded token which is **category**

How can i solve this problem?
Regards

Comment: What are examples of working js/css URLs?

Comment: http://sooq-sud.host56.com/sooq-sud/index_files/bezaatv2_2013_sep_02A.css

Comment: http://sooq-sud.host56.com/sooq-sud/subcategory/index_files/bezaatv2_2013_sep_02A.css this is not working url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both problems are due to your use of relative links.

You can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/mysite/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL `/mysite/` and not from the current page's URL.

---

**Update:** Modified rules:

Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /mysite/

```
 RewriteRule ^.+?/(index_files/.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mysite/[^/]+/([^./]+\.php) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+) category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The problem is, i have no permission to access the source files to update it.

Comment: Difficult to help when you are just modifying server side rule but cannot modify HTML.

Comment: I get access to the source files and all is well after i add the <base href="/mysite/" />